# Show that $|f''(\mu)|\geq\frac{4}{(b-a)^2}[f(b)-f(a)]$ for some $\mu\in(a,b)$ provided that $f'(a)=f'(b)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> Let $f(x)$ be twice differentiable in $(a,b)$ and suppose that $f'(a)=f'(b)=0$. Prove that there exist at least one point $\mu$ in $(a,b)$ such that
>   $$
> |f''(\mu)|\geq\frac{4}{(b-a)^2}[f(b)-f(a)].
> $$

---

I tried Rolle's theorem. Since $f'(a)=f'(b)=0$, there exists at least one $\mu \in (a,b)$ such that
$$
f''(\mu)=0.
$$
I also wrote the right hand side as
$$
\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{(\dfrac{b-a}{2})^2}=\dfrac{\dfrac{f(b)-f(\dfrac{b+a}{2})+f(\dfrac{b+a}{2})-f(a)}{\dfrac{b-a}{2}}}{\dfrac{b-a}{2}}
$$
But I do not know how to do next.

Comment: I see you're posting lots of homework questions here. Have you worked out the earlier ones? You should accept answers if they satisfy you, not just leave them.

Comment: @TedShifrin I am studying advanced calculus by  myself right now, the questions are not my homework. I did up vote to answers which I think was very helpful. But I will leave it there for a little while to see weather there are other solutions for the questions I still confused...Thank you though.

Comment: Have you tried doing what I suggested? If you got stuck, you should follow up with a question.

Comment: @TedShifrin I did try what you said for the previous question, and I just added an comment with that. Thank you Professor~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the mean value theorem, one has
$$
\frac{f(b)-f((b+a)/2)}{(b-a)/2}=f'(\xi_1)
$$
and
$$
\frac{f((b+a)/2)-f(a)}{(b-a)/2}=f'(\xi_2)
$$
for some $\xi_1\in((b+a)/2,b)$ and $\xi_2\in(a,(b+a)/2)$. 
Applying the MVT again,  we have
$$
f'(\xi_2)=f''(\eta_1)(\xi_2-a)
$$
and
$$
f'(\xi_1)=f''(\eta_2)(b-\xi_1).
$$
for some $\eta_i\in(a,b)$. Now, when both $f''(\eta_1), f''(\eta_2)\geq 0$,
adding them up you have
$$
f'(\xi_1)+f'(\xi_2)\leq f''(\eta_3)(b-a)/2
$$
by [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)).

When $f''(\eta_1), f''(\eta_2)<0$, the case is trivial. When $f''(\eta_1)\cdot f''(\eta_2)\leq 0$, I leave it to you.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: Suppose not. Then for $a\le x\le\frac{a+b}2$, $f''(x)\le 4\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{(b-a)^2}$ and for $\frac{a+b}2\le x\le b$, $f''(x)\ge -4\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{(b-a)^2}$. What can you do with this?